# Is there a method to open Wi-Fi settings in Android and provide a path for returning to the calling application?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm developing an app for a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 / 4 which will be embedded into a machine. The back, home, and menu buttons are covered and the only accessible part of the tablet is the touchscreen.

I need to be able to access Wi-Fi settings from the app and return. I can launch the Wi-Fi settings using

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
// Or
startActivity(new Intent(android.net.wifi.WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK);
```

However, once you enter these screens there is no way out without using a hardware button.

I've also tried adding the preferences to a fragment via

```
addPreferencesFromIntent(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
// Or
addPreferencesFromIntent(new Intent(android.net.wifi.WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK);
```

but receive a java.lang.NullPointerException

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(8767): at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromIntent(PreferenceManager.java:249)
E/AndroidRuntime(8767): at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromIntent(PreferenceFragment.java:303)
```

Is there a way to load this screen into a PreferenceFragment, force it to have a "back" button in the top left corner, some other method, or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm developing an app for a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 / 4 which will be embedded into a machine.

Did you ask the machine for permission first? :-)

> I've also tried adding the preferences to a fragment via

That is not going to work, for a variety of reasons, not the least of which being that your app does not have the rights to manipulate those settings.

> Is there a way to load this screen into a PreferenceFragment

Not in a way that will work reliably.

> force it to have a "back" button in the top left corner

You are welcome to start a `Service` that offers some sort of button as a popup floating over the foreground. While that button could not literally do a BACK operation (i.e., call `finish()` on the Settings activity), you could have it use `startActivity()` to bring something of yours back to the foreground.

Your bigger problem is that, IIRC, the user can get to the rest of the Settings app via the home affordance in the action bar, which I presume you would not want.

> some other method

These sorts of embedded scenarios should not be using a stock ROM, IMHO. You should have your own build of Android, with your own facilities for handling all of these scenarios.

Comment: In the long run I will develop a custom ROM, however given the time frame for the initial deadline I have to use stock. So essentially I'm out of luck with my initial approach. I'll have a look into the service with a floating button idea. If I use "Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS" then there is no way into the main settings which is fine for this application. Also, my app restricts access to launching wifi settings so I'm not overly concerned with that.